Effect of changes in the air's nitrogen-oxygen-carbondioxide proportions
I recall (although, perhaps wrongly), from my PADI scuba diving books, that air is made up of 78% nitrogen, 0.8% CO2 and 1.2% O2.
I was wondering, what would happen to our lungs (or to that of any other living creature on Earth), if, that proportion changed.
For instance,
consider
78% nitrogen, 0.9% CO2 and 1.1% O2.
I was wondering, hopefully, my question is a good one (I don't know if it's good or bad), but thank you for your answers, I think this would be intuitive, and shed light, on the workings and life of many living organisms.
Thanks.

The quoted numbers are incorrect; 1.2% O2 is way too low, should be ~20% and CO2 is way too high, should be ~0.04%. Nitrogen is about right. Check the source, try some others. Usually gas proportions are for dry air and leave out water vapor, that varies widely.

The (dry) air in Earth's atmosphere is about 78.08 percent nitrogen, 20.95 percent oxygen, and 0.93 percent Ar. Roughly, 78% N2, 21% O2 and 1% Ar.
CO2 is a mere 0.04%.
If the oxygen content were 1.1-1.2%, we couldn't survive!

As a follow on to Riccardo's answer, dry-air oxygen levels are fairly stable at 20.95% outdoors. The info below is based on OSHA here and here:

Below 19.5% - air is oxygen deficient and one should leave the area

16%–19.5% - decreased ability to work and for tissues to receive oxygen they need, impaired thinking while not at rest

12%–16% - increased breathing rates, increased heartbeat, impaired thinking at rest

10%–14% - faulty judgement, intermittent respiration

6%–10% - nausea, vomiting, lethargy, loss of consciousness. Fatal in about 8 minutes

0%-6% - convulsions, cardiac standstill, fatal in about 40 seconds


When you are exposed to oxygen poor air a body can rapidly release oxygen it has based on  Le Chatelier's principle. Which is why death can occur much quicker than humans can hold their breath.
